# PHP number of hours between current time zone and GMT time zone

Tags: php, time, timezone

I'm looking for a way to find the number of hours of difference between the time zone of the PHP configuration and the GMT time.

For example if the PHP config time zone is set to America/New_York, find the number "-4"
if the in Brussels "+1" etc.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean "-4" for America/New York or do you want the reverse of the GMT difference?

Comment: Oooopps -4 yes i'll edit thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Err, what if you try ;) ?

```
date('O');
```

Comment: yep this then : (date('O')*1/100)

Comment: Funny I was thinking it will not be that easy really! ;) thank you

Comment: And `date('Z')` will get you seconds, if that's easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [date_default_timezone_get()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php) to get the timezone that has been set and determine based on this what the difference is from GMT.  It will return the value from date_default_timezone_set() or the value set in date.timezone in the php.ini file.